# Access UDP Datagram from a QByteArray

Tags: c++, c, qt, qbytearray

I'm not sure I understand how the QByteArray Object works as of yet (it's raw char data, right?), but here's my dilemma:

I'm trying to access data from a UDP datagram in a function. Code:

```
QByteArray buffer;  
buffer.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
QHostAddress sender;
quint16 senderPort;
udpSocket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &sender, &senderPort);
```

This frees up the buffer for other incoming data and allows me to process my current datagram.

As far as I can tell, I must store the data in a QByteArray, because any other attempt has made the compiler very cross with me. Regardless, the data stored in the QByteArray is a series of unsigned 16 bit values(commands) that I need to access. Can it be read directly out of the QByteArray, and if so, how? I've had no luck doing so. If not, what's the best way to convert the entire array to quint16 array so that I can process the incoming data? Thanks All!!

Comment: `QByteArray` is an array of bytes. To convert to a 16 bit unsigned integer value, you have to take two adjacent bytes from the `buffer` and use `buffer[n]*0xFF+buffer[n+1]` if the sender uses a big-endian system. Change the order if it is in little-endian system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have read the data with readDatagram, you need to access it in quint16 values.

Two possible methods:

1. Use a quint16 buffer and store directly into it:

   ```
   //Set 1024 to any large enough size
   QVector<quint16> buffer(1024);
   qint64 readBytes = udpSocket->readDatagram((char*)buffer.data(),
                                              buffer.size()*sizeof(qint16),
                                              &sender,
                                              &senderPort);
   buffer.resize(readBytes/sizeof(quint16));
   //Now buffer contains the read values, nothing more.
   ```
2. Use a QByteArray and "unserialize" it to quint16 values. This approach is more complex but is cleaner, since you have options for interpreting data format, such as endianness.

   ```
   //Set 2048 to any large enough size
   QByteArray buffer(2048);
   qint64 readBytes = udpSocket->readDatagram(buffer.data(),
                                              buffer.size(),
                                              &sender,
                                              &senderPort);
   buffer.resize(readBytes);

   QDataStream dataStream(&buffer, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

   //Configure QDataStream here, for instance:
   //dataStream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

   while(!dataStream.atEnd())
   {
       quint16 readValue;
       dataStream >> readValue;

       //do something with readValue here
   }
   ```

Comment: apologies, I left out the extra code that reflected your remarks in an attempt to keep this post small. I have corrected it.

Comment: I've never used QDataStream so I'll assume it's a tool to handle data conversions? I'll look it up. Anyways, my C++ is a little shaky (newb) so I'll ask - readValue is a 16 bit array containing the data stored in the QByteArray?

Comment: @galinette: UDP datagram size should not larger than 512 bytes (fragmentation problem). Theoretically maximum for an UDP datagram is 65507 bytes (IPv4).

Comment: Yes, QDataStream it's a class for encoding/decoding binary data.

Comment: readValue is not an array, it's a single unsigned 16-bit int. This is in a loop, so at each iteration, you have the next 16-bit value, until everything is read. It's yours to fill a 16bit array as you like.

Comment: I see, I think I have an understanding now - did a little more reading - thanks for the info on this!!! I appreciate the help!!

Comment: By the way, if both sender and receiver are written by you using Qt, you may use QDataStream for encoding the QVector<quint16> on sending size, and QDataStream for reading it on receiving side, in just one command.